# Can't compile an OCaml program that uses sqlite3 module using dune

Tags: sqlite, ocaml, ocaml-dune

I wanted to test the Sqlite3 bindings in OCaml.

I have downloaded the appropriate package with `opam`, it works fine using `utop`.
I have tested it like this:

```
#use "topfind";;
#require "sqlite3";;
#show Sqlite3;;
open Sqlite3
let db = db_open "yolo";;
let _ = db_close db;;
```

The problem is I can't use the same module in a program compiled with dune. Here is the exact code I try to compile:
(content of `main.ml` file)

```
let _ = Sqlite3.sqlite_version ();;
```

(content of `dune` file)

```
(executable
    (name main)
    (libraries sqlite3)
)
```

When I try to compile it using `dune build` I get `Unbound value Sqlite3.sqlite_version`.
It does not happen with other packages (checked `yojson` and it works as intended).

EDIT: It is worth noting that opening `Sqlite3` (i.e. `open Sqlie3`) module in an .ml file works. It just using any of the functions inside results in error.

Comment: Is your project just main.ml and this dune file? Nothing else in the directory?

Comment: There are other files. All of them were generated using `dune init proj sqlite` and then `dune init exe main`. I've modified dune and main file in the `sqlite` folder as described in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is very simple.

Do NOT name your project the same as a library you want to use in it.

I have created a project named "sqlite3" using `dune init proj sqlite3` hence it automatically generated a boilerplate for a library named the same.

Naming it any other way solved the problem.